# C - How to get original value of when you pass a dereferenced value to a function to later be compare with another string?

Tags: c, reference, dereference

I know homework help are shunned upon, however, I have intense coder's block.

**I want help understanding more than anything.**

So when I take the address of the variable (**&c**) I understand that I get an address to its location in memory, but I don't know how to dereference that address in order to access its specific value (**'b'**) to be compared in the function (**color(&c, total**) it is used in.

*The main cannot be changed for any reason due to the requirements of the assignment*

```
typedef struct dragon
{
    char *name;
    char *color[3];
    int numHead;
    int numTail;

}dragon;

void color(char* color, dragon *d);

int main()
{

dragon total[4];
dragon_info(total);
char c = 'b';
color(&c, total);
return 0;
}
```

Eventually, I used this line to see if the colors matched

```
if(strcmp(color, d[currentDra].color[currentColor]);
```

Before I used the line below because from my from my first perspective they would char

```
if(color ==  d[currentDra].color[currentColor])
```

But after debugging for a while I realized that **color** was just an address

Overall, I need to somehow get the value of **color** using the address somehow.
*color doesn't find the value.
&color doesn't either.

The rest of the function

```
void color(char *color, dragon *d)
{
    char *colorList[5] = {"red","blue","white","green","yellow"}; 
    int colorShow;
    int knownColor = 1;
    printf("what is color? ==== %p\n", color);
    if(*color == 'r')
    {
        colorShow = 0;
    }
    else if(*color == 'b')
    {
        colorShow = 1;
    }
    else if(*color == 'w')
    {
        colorShow = 2;
    }
    else if(*color == 'g')
    {
        colorShow = 3;
    }
    else if(*color == 'y')
    {
        colorShow = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry that is an unknown color, exiting...\n");
        knownColor = 0;
    }
    

    //if a char then = numbers 0-1
    //one loop for the dragons
    if(knownColor)
    {
        printf("***All the %s dragons:***\n", colorList[colorShow]);
        int currentDra;
        for(currentDra = 0; currentDra < 4; currentDra++)
        {
            //another loop for the colors of the dragon
            int currentColor;
            for(currentColor = 0; currentColor < 3; currentColor++)
            {
                //printf("%c\n\n", (char*)color);

                if(strcmp(color, d[currentDra].color[currentColor]))
                {
                   printf("%s is %s\n", d[currentDra].name, colorList[colorShow]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much this is my first question ever.

Comment: Why doesn't `*color` give you the value that `color` points to?

Comment: How is `dragon` defined?

Comment: typedef struct dragon
    {
     char *name;
     char *color[3];
     int numHead;
     int numTail;

    }dragon;

Comment: sorry I don't know how to code block in comments :(

Comment: I think you're on to something though, maybe the problem I'm having has to do with the address of the value of dragon's char instead.

Comment: Tough to tell exactly what you are trying to compare. But your strcmp is probably wrong. I actually think it's undefined behavior since `color` is not null terminated. If you are just trying to compare the first character of `color` with the character 
at `d [currentDra].color[currentColor]` then why does `if(*color == d [currentDra].color[currentColor])` not work?

Comment: When I use 'if(*color == d [currentDra].color[currentColor])' I receive a **warning: comparison b/w pointer and integer** error

Comment: Right. I missed that. You need to figure out what exactly you are trying to compare. I don't think I can help you until you figure that out. What *exactly* is stored in `dragon.color`?

Comment: On the topic of "shunned upon homework help": Most people here accept the compromise described here or at least tolerate people acting according to it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: For formatting code in a comment use the backward tick `\`...\``. But do not use it to add additional information to a question. Instead [edit] your question to add it right in there.

Comment: You got the use of the term "dereference" wrong. I edited your question to fix.

Comment: `dragon.color` stores single char as string literals for example, `dragon.color[0]` will equal "b" for blue. But also `dragon.color` will always have three values [0] [1] [2] forming an array of string literals.

Comment: @Yunnosch ty for the newbie help ^^

Comment: Ok. Then `strcmp` won't work because `color` is not null terminated. If it's always just one character, use `if(color[0] ==  d[currentDra].color[currentColor][0])`

Comment: @MFisherKDX Wow. I would've never found the answer without you! I have never seen a case like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(strcmp(color, d[currentDra].color[currentColor]);`

This doesn't work because `color`, as passed, is not null terminated. Thus this is undefined behavior.

`if(color ==  d[currentDra].color[currentColor])`

This doesn't work because you are comparing the pointers and not the values they reference.

If `dragon.color` is an array that contains single character strings, then you can compare with:

`if(color[0] == d[currentDra].color[currentColor][0])`